# Sharepoint 2013 List WYSIWYG Designer views

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, custom-list, xslt-list-view-web-part, caml

We need to offer our users a way to freeform format Custom List fields anywhere on a SharePoint page. The designer can not be InfoPath, SharePoint Designer or Reporting Services.

Design experience needs to be drag and drop WYSIWYG.

We'd like the connection to SharePoint to be via the API or Odata.

If It's possible with visual Studio 2013 we would very interested. Or possibly if there is another product like an HTML5 editor that can do this?

We would like these pages to hosted and secured inside SharePoint Online 2013.

Comment: I have used TinyMCE in the past for some rich text fields on particular lists, that might be useful, or perhaps there is a markdown library that could work.

Comment: will that work for page design and layout enabling users to place fields anywhere on the page?

Comment: ah, probably not, I didn't interpret this as a page design problem since you were mentioning fields.